# How do I debug websites in IE10 on Win8 under Metro?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a website that runs fine on IE10 Consumer Preview, Chrome, and Firefox all on Windows 8 Consumer Preview (i.e. Win8 beta). But in the Metro version of IE10 Consumer Preview I just see an error message: "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". How do I diagnose the error? F12 does not bring up any developer tools.

Comment: Does your page reference any controls?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there by controls Rowland, but no; it is all HTML, JavaScript (including some jQuery on one page) and CSS.

Comment: I meant things like Flash etc. Is the page publicly visible at all to try from somewhere else?

Comment: Not easily. I know it does work on other Win8 IE10 Metro machines, but it doesn't work on 2. I'm really after 'how-to diagnose'

Comment: if it works on most machines but not 2, it's probably an IE bug which is to be expected during beta.  jiggle the machines around a bit, reboot, and then try again.

Comment: There are two problems- one is fixing the site, the other is knowing how to debug under IE10 beta running in Metro on Win8 (beta). The reboot may fix the site (though it doesn't in this case) but it doesn't help the 'how to diagnose'.

Comment: Try the visual studio dom inspector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the infamous [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) http debugger works with windows 8, allowing you to see what requests and responses are being sent to and from the server, so the browser can not hide anything from you, which is what I suspect is happening at the moment.

Comment: Will fiddler on the Win 8 desktop see network activity from Metro?

Comment: yes, I could see all the requests for images made from my metro app

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended to use firebug lite in IE because the native debugger is poor

Add this line to developed website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```